# android studio: how to regenerate build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, build

Is there way to have android studio automatically rebuild build.gradle?

I have a case where the compileSdkVersion is wrong (says 18, should be 22).  I changed it in the AndroidManifest.xml file but that change did not propagate to the build file.  I tried build-clean project, build-rebuild project to no avail.

Obviously I can change it by hand but I would prefer to see a solution that is more automatic and less prone to errors I might unwittingly introduce.

Comment: `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion` etc are defined in gradle file now and you should change it accordingly yourself in gradle file instead of changing in AndroidManifest.

Comment: So, will the manifest be updated automatically to match the build file?  What does one do to ensure they stay consistent.  Or is this a tool failure?

Comment: Why you want to update manifest file? You don't need `compileSdkVersion` in manifest file at all anymore. New build tools look for compileSdkVersion in gradle.build file. If it's not found then look for it in manifest as alternative but you don't really need to provide in manifest anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official Android page: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

> The **defaultConfig** element configures core settings and entries in the
> manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) dynamically from the build system.
>
> The values in **defaultConfig** override those in the manifest file. The
> configuration specified in the defaultConfig element applies to all
> build variants, unless the configuration for a build variant overrides
> some of these values.

You should provide sdk version only in gradle.build file once. If you provide any sdk settings in `AndroidManifest.xml` it will be overridden by build system with the values in your gradle.build file.

If you create a new project in your latest Android Studio you will notice that Android doesn't put any API version related settings in manifest file anymore. They all go to gradle.build file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I guess one could say the import from Eclipse is buggy: it should have removed the statements from manifest.